# In Google Chrome, This feature is very inconvenient

Tags: google-chrome

In Google Chrome, whenever a folder is clicked, it is rendered according to the folder on the screen.

In other words, look at the picture below!

[image]

The mouse cursor does not appear in this video.

But the mouse doesn't move, it just stays in place.

Automatically wraps when clicked!

This is very inconvenient and non-user experience. it's so painful

It's really difficult to edit one by one

How can I get rid of this feature (or bug)?

Comment: Are you looking for https://superuser.com or https://support.google.com? cuz SO is for programming questions

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at this site